# Custom iOS Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

I am interested in creating a custom layout for my iPhone (No, I am not an Apple Developer, and paying $100 /yr is not worth it for this). I would like to be able to place whatever key, in whatever location on the keyboard (For example adding the “<” “\” and “>” keys to the main layout). I saw some apps that might be able to do it, but they require a subscription of up-front purchase. If anyone has a (Free) solution, please let me know.
Thanks!

Note: I don't want to jailbreak my device :)

Comment: What about this one?    http://unicode.lacanoid.net

Comment: I’ll keep it in mind if a free solution can’t be found. Thanks for the link!